# Enabling sql server connections from external ip

Tags: sql-server, networking, tcp

I feel like i've done everything to try and open the ports for external users to connect to my SQL Server...

In Sql Server Configuration, i've enabled listen all and set the TCP port under ipAll to 1433.

In windows firewall i've created 3 inbound exceptions, one for tcp 1433, one for udp 1434, and one for SQL Server program itself

In my router settings i've literally disabled the firewall, and enabled port forwarding for TCP 1433 and UDP 1434.

Is there anything i've missed to get this connection to work? In my java application I can connect to the database if I use my local IP of 10.0.0.34, but cannot connect if I use my external IP. The error I am receiving is connection timed out and then instructions to check my firewall etc.

If I use portqry with my ip on port 1433, it says the port is associated with the m-sql-server service (which is correct), but that the port is "FILTERED" instead of "LISTENING"

Comment: The SQL Server log will record the IP and port it's actually listening on.

Comment: Well, the executable "Portqry" mentions that tcp port (ms-sql-s service) is filtered. I've added inbound exceptions to the windows firewall and yet it still wont listen.

Comment: I've looked at the logs and it says 1433 is the port it is listening on.

Comment: did you check running state of sql browser service?

Comment: sql server browser is running, but I am unable to start Sql server agent.

Comment: Sql server browser and sql server (SQLEXPRESS) are both running, but Sql Server Agent cannot start

Comment: what is your connection string?

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.34:1433;DatabaseName=MyDatabase

Comment: That is my connection string, it works with the local ip.. but when i substitute the local ip with the external one it says connection timed out. This is why I think it is a port issue. I have opened TCP 1433, UDP 1434 on windows firewall and modified the configuration to have ipall TCP 1433 but still to no avail

Comment: Can you test connecting to SQL Server "external ip" from the SQL Server?

Comment: @DavidBrowne I am unable to connect to the server using the public ip address. I can, however, connect to the server using my local ip address 10.0.0.34. I have checked the settings under Server Properties -> Remote server connections, and the checkbox for allow remote connections to the server is checked. This makes me believe it is a windows firewall issue, but I have created 3 inbound exceptions in the windows firewall. One for tcp 1433, one for udp 1434, and one for the sql server executable itself.

Comment: I have also executed a query I found online, which looks through the logs for the TCP port the server is listening on, and it is returning 1433 for ipv6 and 1433 for ipv4. I have disabled ipv6 in my network options, however.

Comment: I've re-enabled ipv6... and I am able to connect to the ipv6 IP from Sql Server mgmt... I wonder why I am not able to connect to my ipv4 ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named SQL instances listen on dynamic ports. This is the function of the Sql Server Browser Service to inform the clients of the actual port. The Sql Browser listens on UDP 1434 and answers all client request with the port number the current instance is using. Sql Server Browser service is required for both TCP and named pipes protocols. SQL Server Browser is used by clients transparently and there is no need for special configuration.

To configure SQL Server Express to allow remote connections, you must complete these steps:

1. Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want to connect to from a remote computer.
2. Configure SQL server to listen on static port
3. Turn on the SQL Server Browser service.
4. Configure the firewall to allow network traffic that is related to SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service.

for detail see 
[How to configure SQL Express 2012 to accept remote connections](https://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/)

Add [instanceName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url) to ConnectionString:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.34;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=MyDatabase
```

Comment: I disable and then re-enabled the TCP/IP option under Protocols for SQLExpress and then I did the netstat -ano | find /i pid and I only received two lines when the example has at least 10. Any idea why?

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8224                        

  TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING       8224